# Android recyclerView with cardview layout issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, recyclerview-layout

[image: Desired Layout Output]

[image: MY current Output as I am using RecyclerView with Cardview]

I am creating a layout as show in the First image.
I am using RecyclerView with Cardview to complete this screen but as you can see in the emulator output i am not getting the desired layout(shown in the first Image) as it looks crazy as all items should be aligned respectively just like HTML Table in the WEB and should work same on all devices.

Here is my Layout Resource XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHomeTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewStatus"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewHomeTeamLogo"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewHomeTeam"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewHomeTeamLogo"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMatchStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewStatus"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewHomeTeamLogo"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewAwayTeamLogo"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewScore"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAwayTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewAwayTeamLogo"
        android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please correct me what is missing.

Comment: Why don't you use Studio preview to inspect your item layout?

Comment: I would recommend you to use ConstraintLayout instead RelativeLayout and to rearrange you views in Android studio Design mode

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xltg.png) is what I get in Studio with your layout ... there are many things you need to fix, but it's a good exercise for you to learn how to build Android layouts ... start wrapping content and adding margins, and also think about responsiveness against different screen sizes

Comment: You can use LinearLayout inside CardView and then use weightSum in linear layout to divide the view as per you need

Comment: yes its  
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

 now i am using constraint layout but its not working across all screens as in landscape mode it does not expand to whole screen.

@Alessio Although it does show correct in landscape in android studio design mode but when i run it on emulator or install apk on android device it does show full width in the landscape mode

Comment: @Nouman you've to change the way you think the layout. It's a good learning, worth it. You can't clearly think it left to right, because assuming each view wraps around its content, it will never expand to the full width. So, you need instead to introduce the idea of columns (you've 7), each with a weight to make them proportional. Then when you add each view to the column, you can center it. It will work, as long as you don't have extremely long strings. Try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your **onCreateViewHolder** with following one

```
@Override
    public CountryListAdapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout."your_layout", null);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);

        CountryListAdapter viewHolder = new CountryListAdapter(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linear layout with horizontal orientation inside card view.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am giving you rough layout might help you,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FT"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_drawable"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHomeTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textViewStatus"
        android:text="Arsenol" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewHomeTeamLogo"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textViewHomeTeam"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewHomeTeamLogo"
        android:text="21:00"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMatchStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewStatus"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewHomeTeamLogo"
        android:text="Not Started" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewAwayTeamLogo"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textViewMatchStatus"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAwayTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewAwayTeamLogo"
        android:text="Leisure city" />
```

Comment: I am using the constraint layout now its working good in the portrait view but its not good in the landscape view.
how should i manage the responsive

Answer (score 0):

update your layout with below layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```